# Save a protected Excel Workbook data in PHPMyAdmin with PHP and HTML code

Tags: php, excel, database

I everyone,

I make a database to archive some excel files with PHPExcel and PHP my admin, but the excel workbook needs to be protected, how can I open the entire workbook with a password in PHP code? Is it possible?

When the excel file is without password the code works perfectly and all the data of excel workbook goes to the database.

Thanks in advance!

Here it is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0); // ocult errors

mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                        mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET character_set_connection=utf8");
                        mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET character_set_client=utf8");
                        mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET character_set_results=utf8");


$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "2019"); //change the year on "2019"
mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf8'); //put accentuation of words 
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST["import"]))
{
 $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["excel"]["name"])); // For getting Extension of selected file
 $allowed_extension = array("xls", "xlsx", "csv"); //allowed extension
 if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension)) //check selected file extension is present in allowed extension array
 {
  $file = $_FILES["excel"]["tmp_name"]; // getting temporary source of excel file
  include("Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php"); // Add PHPExcel Library in this code
  $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file); // create object of PHPExcel library by using load() method and in load method define path of selected file

  $output .= "<label class='text-success'>Data Inserted</label><br /><table class='table table-bordered'>"; //table in html page
  foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
  {

   /* echo 'Worksheet number - ', $objPHPExcel->getIndex($worksheet), PHP_EOL; */ //see the number of every sheet from excel

   $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
   for($row=5; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
   {
    $output .= "<tr>";

    $point = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $c = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $d = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $f = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $g = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $h = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $i = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $j = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getCalculatedValue());
    $k = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getCalculatedValue());

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_excel(point, description, c, d, e, f, g,h,i,j,k) VALUES ('".$point."','".$description."', '".$c."', '".$d."', '".$e."', '".$f."', '".$g."', '".$h."', '".$i."', '".$j."', '".$k."')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $output .= '<td>'.$point.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$description.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$c.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$d.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$e.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$f.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$g.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$h.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$j.'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$k.'</td>';
    $output .= '</tr>';
   }
  } 
  $output .= '</table>';

 }
 else
 {
  $output = '<label class="text-danger">Invalid File</label>'; //if non excel file then
 }
}
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Import Excel to Mysql using PHPExcel in PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
  <style>
  body
  {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  .box
  {
   width:700px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   background-color:#fff;
   border-radius:5px;
   margin-top:100px;
  }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container box">
   <h3 align="center">Import Excel to Mysql using PHPExcel in PHP</h3><br />
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Select Excel File</label>
    <input type="file" name="excel" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="import" class="btn btn-info" value="Import" />
   </form>
   <br />
   <br />
   <?php
   echo $output;
      ?>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Yes, in programming everything is possible. Please share your code that works perfectly without password. Possibly stackoverflowists can help you develop that to work with password protected files. If you already have tried something regarding that, it would be super to share that, too.

Comment: Thanks @Veikko the code is already in the description.